# Plotting multiple graphs in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, plot

I am trying to plot a number of sets in different windows in the following way:

```
Qa_plot = (start:step:stop);

for i = 1 : nImg
    custom_title = strcat(custom_title, int2str(i));
    figure;
    hold on
    xlabel('Qa')
    ylabel('TV')
    title(custom_title)
    plot(Qa_plot, cell2mat(TV_original), '--r', 'userdata', '-- original')
    plot(Qa_plot, cell2mat(TV_attacked), '-b', 'userdata', '- dithered')
    legend(get(gca, 'children'), get(get(gca, 'children'), 'userdata'))
end
```

However, there are multiple graphs that overlap one another in the same figure upon execution. How may I create a separate figure/graph on each iteration without containing information from the previous ones?

Comment: Having the call to 'figure' in the loop should create different figures; out of curiosity does it change if you comment the call to legend? And is it normal that neither TV_original nor TV_attacked uses the loop index 'i'?

Comment: The call to legend you mean? That's good to know thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Using the "figure" followed by the "hold on" command should create a new plot in each iteration of the loop. If there are more than two plots in each axes/figure (you have two plot calls), then one plot call creates more than one graph/plot. This is the case when cell2mat(...) results in a matrix rather than a vector, in which case each column is plotted as a separate graph. If this really is the issue, you can choose which column to plot by

```
data = cell2mat(...);
plot(Qa_plot, temp(:,columnIdx), '--r', ....)
```